# How to hide a row in cxGrid unbound mode

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tcxgrid

How can I hide a row in cxGrid unbound mode?

It's been hours already and I can't figure it out. I googled it and failed.

Comment: Did you try this [recommendation](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ50238) in the DevExpress website?

Comment: Nope, because it suggests me to use bounded(with dataset) cxgrid and I don't want my grid to be bounded, i want it to be unbound.

Comment: You can use OnFilterRecord nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a sample app with a grid in `unbound mode` and used the `OnFilterRecord` as suggested by `DevExpress` in its [recommendation](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ50238), and it works fine.

Following you can see my test code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    testLevel: TcxGridLevel;
    testGrid: TcxGrid;
    testView: TcxGridTableView;
    testViewColumn1: TcxGridColumn;
    testViewColumn2: TcxGridColumn;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure tviewDataControllerFilterRecord(
      ADataController: TcxCustomDataController; ARecordIndex: Integer;
      var Accept: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  testView.DataController.RecordCount := testView.DataController.RecordCount + 1;
  testView.DataController.Values[testView.DataController.RecordCount - 1,0] := 'foo';
  testView.DataController.Values[testView.DataController.RecordCount - 1,1] := 'bar';

  testView.DataController.RecordCount := testView.DataController.RecordCount + 1;
  testView.DataController.Values[testView.DataController.RecordCount - 1,0] := 'foo2';
  testView.DataController.Values[testView.DataController.RecordCount - 1,1] := 'bar2';
end;

procedure TForm1.tviewDataControllerFilterRecord(
  ADataController: TcxCustomDataController; ARecordIndex: Integer;
  var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := (testView.DataController.Values[ARecordIndex,0] <> 'foo');
end;
```

And the result:

[image: hiding row in unbound cxGrid]